# What stats do traded Pokemon keep?

Tags: pokemon-series

When you trade a Pokemon, what kind of stats does it keep? Besides the obvious extra experience gain, what other effects are there? Mainly I'm looking at **happiness/friendship** or even the EV stats.

Example, if I received a Golbat with a happiness/friendship level at max, can I then level him up to evolve to Crobat? Or does that stat reset upon being traded.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Friendship), trading affects friendship level differently for each generation of the game. I will outlay it in each generation below:

First Generation: Trading will reset to 0
Second Generation: Trading will reset to 70
Third Generation: Trading will reset it to base stats (usually 70 or 140, [full list here](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_base_friendship))
Fourth Generation: Trading will reset it to base stats
Fifth Generation: Trading will reset it to base stats

Thus, no matter what generation the trade is completed in, a freshly traded Golbat will not evolve upon a level up.

Stats other than happiness, such as Effort Values (EVs) and Individual Values (IVs) will however, be preserved.